# Add a python dependency to to a snap package

Tags: application-development, pip, snap

I am creating a snap app and I need to install a python dependency using

```
pip3 install <lib>
```

How can I do it using snapcraft?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in IRC. You need to use the python3 plugin specifying the dependencies in a list

```
parts:
  py:
    plugin: python3
    python-packages:
      - <my-dependency>
```